# Update dataframe row from a series

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe called state_df:

```
                  abc, xyz
exchange, symbol
JSE,      MTN,    123, 546
          OML,    674, 235
CME,      ES,     235, 563
          YM,     453, 356
```

So basically what this represents is a list of columns where the index is a combination of exchange+symbol.

I select a row from this dataframe based on a specific exchange + symbol combination (which will be unique and therefore results in a pandas series):

```
result = state_df.loc[exchange, symbol]
```

I pass the resulting series to another module where several operations are performed. Ultimately the series is returned at which point I need to update the original dataframe with the updated row.

I know there is a DataFrame.update method, but this seems to only be for updating a dataframe by using another dataframe.

In my case I need to update the original dataframe from the newly modified series. The name of the series would of course be the same as the index row that needs to be updated in the dataframe.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple reassignment should do the trick:

```
df.loc['JSE', 'OML'] = df.loc['JSE', 'OML'].apply(np.sqrt)
```

The full code to play around:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
'exchange' : ['JSE', 'JSE', 'CME', 'CME'],
'symbol'   : ['MTN', 'OML',  'ES',  'YM'],
'abc'      : [ 123 ,  674 ,  235 ,  453 ],
'xyz'      : [ 546 ,  235 ,  563 ,  365 ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(['exchange', 'symbol'])

# apply fancy calculation
df.loc['JSE', 'OML'] = df.loc['JSE', 'OML'].apply(np.sqrt)
print df
```

Which results in the following `DataFrame`:

```
                       abc        xyz
exchange symbol                      
JSE      MTN     123.00000  546.00000
         OML      25.96151   15.32971 # square root is here
CME      ES      235.00000  563.00000
         YM      453.00000  365.00000
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do just simple:

```
state_df.loc[exchange, symbol] = updated_result
```